# Upload Data to Meteor / Mongo DB

Tags: mongodb, csv, import, upload, meteor

I have a Meteor app and would like to upload data (from csv) to a meteor collection.

I have found:

- solutions (e.g. [Collectionfs](https://github.com/CollectionFS/Meteor-CollectionFS)) which deal with file uploads
- methods for [uploading directl](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongoimport/#bin.mongoimport)y to the underlying mongo db from the shell
- references to meteor router - but I am using the excellent [iron-router](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router), which does not appear to provide this functionality

My requirement is that the app user be able to upload csv data to the app from within the app.  I do not need to store the csv file anywhere within the app file structure, I just need to *read* the csv data to the collection.

It is possible that I cannot figure out how to do this because my terms of reference ('upload data to meteor') are ambiguous or incorrect.  Or that I am an idiot.

Comment: You can just insert data into a collection right on the client, and meteor will take care of 'uploading' it to the server. This is what I'm doing in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've solved this problem in the past using [this gist of mine](https://gist.github.com/chfritz/8361579), together with this code (using the [jquery-csv](https://code.google.com/p/jquery-csv/) plugin to parse the csv data). This is done on the client side and is independent of using iron-router or not. It would be fairly straightforward to move the insertion code into a Meteor method, uploading the csv file first and then parsing and inserting the data on the server. I've tried that, too, but didn't see any performance improvement.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var dd = new dragAndDrop({
        onComplete: function(files) {
            for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                // Only process csv files.
                if (!f.type.match('text/csv')) {
                    continue;
                }
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onloadend = function(event) {
                    var all = $.csv.toObjects(event.target.result);
                    // do something with file content
                    _.each(all, function(entry) { 
                         Items.insert(entry);
                    });
                }
             }
        }
     });

     dd.add('upload-div'); // add to an existing div, turning it into a drop container
});
```

Beware though that if you are inserting a lot of entries, then you are better off turning all reactive rerendering off for a while, until all of them are inserted. Otherwise, both node on the server and the browser tab will get really slow. See my suggested solution here: [Meteor's subscription and sync are slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12298640/meteors-subscription-and-sync-are-slow/19599027#19599027)

Comment: This is spot-on.  I have accepted this answer but included the code that I actually used (which is stripped back a bit).  Many thanks.

Answer (score 6):

[ChristianF's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21053576/2581585) is spot on and I have accepted it as the correct answer.  However, it provides even more than I need at this stage, so I am including here the code I have actually used - which is largely taken from Christian's answer and other elements I have found as a result:

**HTML UPLOAD BUTTON** (I am not including drag and drop at this stage)

```
<template name="upload">
  <input type="file" id="files" name="files[]" multiple />
  <output id="list"></output>
</template>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
Template.upload.events({
  "change #files": function (e) {
    var files = e.target.files || e.dataTransfer.files;
    for (var i = 0, file; file = files[i]; i++) {
      if (file.type.indexOf("text") == 0) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onloadend = function (e) {
          var text = e.target.result;
          console.log(text)
          var all = $.csv.toObjects(text);
          console.log(all)
          _.each(all, function (entry) {
            Members.insert(entry);
          });
        }
        reader.readAsText(file);
      }
    }
  }
})
```

NB there is a jquery-csv library for Meteor here: https://github.com/donskifarrell/meteor-jquery-csv